# How to resolve Kreait \ Firebase \ Exception \ ApiException (400) invalid_grant for firebase

Tags: laravel, firebase, invalidation

I am facing **invalid_grant** problem again and again. I am trying to implement **firebase** to my **laravel** project.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Kreait\Firebase;
use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;
use Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount;
use Kreait\Firebase\Database;
```

.............................

And This is my store function:

..............................

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $serviceAccount = ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile(__DIR__.'/resturant-f7e23-firebase-adminsdk-sziig-4bd11864d7.json');
        $firebase = (new Factory)
            ->withServiceAccount($serviceAccount)
            ->withDatabaseUri('https://resturant-f7e23.firebaseio.com/')
            ->create();

        $db = $firebase->getDatabase();

        $db->getReference('reserves/'.'1')
        ->set([
            'name' => 'John',
            'emails' => 'john@gmail.com',
            'website' => 'http://john.com',
            ]);

        return ('You did it');
    }
```

[firebase invalid_grant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKW25.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just Update your device's date and time. It will be fixed. The problem was with my machine's date time. If you are behind from the time zone you are in, the invalid_grant error will occur.

Comment: Just for future reference, there are a couple of situations that can bring "invalid_grant". Please follow [this link](https://blog.timekit.io/google-oauth-invalid-grant-nightmare-and-how-to-fix-it-9f4efaf1da35) where Lasse B. Andersen explains and helps to solve each one.

Comment: Token errors in Firebase, I learnt the hard way, was due to the Server's (Web host) time not set correctly. So if you update the timezone and time, it should work out. did for me on a new hosting server.